# Change Icon in JFrame (get rid of the Cup)

Tags: java, jframe, icons

as an excercise I have to change the Icon of my JFrame to my companies logo.
But no matter, what I try, it wont change.

```
 public class window extends JFrame
{
private JTextField dateiname;

JLabel textdatei;
String[] choice = { "", "Berechtigung anlegen", "Tabelle erstellen",    "Stammdaten anlegen" };

String intext="";
JTextArea ausgabe = new JTextArea(intext,19,10);

public      ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("tqg.JPG");
public window()
{

    super("SQL-Code-Vorlage");
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    setSize(400, 400);
    setIconImage(icon.getImage());
```

I put the "tqg.jpg" in the src folder, the main folder of the project, I also tried to put it in a folder /images. It just doesn't change the logo.

//It has been fixed with this

```
  try
    {
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new     File("tqg.png"));

        Image image = ImageIO.read(inputStream);

        this.setIconImage(image);
    } catch (IOException e1)
    {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When you use jpg, ImageIcon asks for a coment and if there is none, you'll get a nullpointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the frame in the `setIconImage()`

```
URL iconURL = getClass().getResource("/package name/tqg.JPG"); // path of the image
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(iconURL);
frame.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
```